# SQL Selecting rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL I have two different tables:

```
Users (with columns: ID, FullName, Email) - Example:
ID   FullName   Email
1    Jack Jhon  JJ@gmail.com
2    Reev Stad  RS@gmail.com
3    Barak Oba  BA@gmail.com
Employees (with columns: ID, FullName, Email, MobilePhone)
1    Ringo Sta  RS2@gmail.com
2    Ami Lingo  AL@gmail.com
3    Jack Jhon  JJ@gmail.com
```

I would like to create one table, with one column only, that will display the FullName coulmns from Both tables and if one name is already exist, it would not be showen twice, LIke this:

```
Jack Jhon
Ami Lingo
Barak Oba
Ringo Sta
Reev Stad
```

How to I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180026(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
SELECT FullName FROM Users
UNION
SELECT FullName FROM Employees
```

Since you're running in collation problems, you can use this syntax instead:

```
SELECT FullName COLLATE database_default FROM Users
UNION
SELECT FullName COLLATE database_default FROM Employees
```

You might want to replace `database_default` with the most appropriate collation for your use-case, or clean up collations in different tables to all be the same. Do note that the collation issue is not strictly related to your question.

Comment: It says Error: Can not resolve the collation between "Hebrew_100..." to "SQL Latin General..."

Comment: @Kasper555 Did you try "the most appropriate collation for your use-case" as Lukas Eder suggested?  If your tables are in different databases you'll need to be more specific about the collation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct fullname from (Select fullname from users
Union
Select fullname from employees
) as drvtbl
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260659/collation-conflict-in-sql-union-all-query

Comment: `UNION` already removes duplicates. There's no need for wrapping the union in a derived table and applying `DISTINCT`, in this case